# Is this a memory leak in Solr?

Tags: java, solr, memory-leaks, jvm, heap-memory

We are running Solr 4.10 and seeing very high response times:

```
avgRequestsPerSecond:2.5
5minRateReqsPerSecond:5.2
75thPcRequestTime:3.45
95thPcRequestTime:16.68
99thPcRequestTime:1366.22
999thPcRequestTime:3477.79
```

On running the `jstat -gc`, I see that the OC and OU are remaining equal while `FGC` is happening continuously. This clearly indicates a memory leak in Solr, right? How can I analyze this further?

```
jstat -gc 32110 1s | awk '{print $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $6 "\t" $7 "\t" $8 "\t" $15 }'
S0U S1U     EU          OC          OU      FGC
0.0 0.0 6632870.9   12582912.0  12402105.3  29902
0.0 0.0 6684761.8   12582912.0  12402105.2  29902
0.0 0.0 6691460.8   12582912.0  12402105.2  29902
0.0 0.0 6694722.4   12582912.0  12402105.2  29903
0.0 0.0 6694725.9   12582912.0  12402105.2  29904
0.0 0.0 6695870.2   12582912.0  12402105.0  29904
0.0 0.0 6729501.5   12582912.0  12402105.0  29904
0.0 0.0 6732006.7   12582912.0  12402105.0  29906
0.0 0.0 6733112.6   12582912.0  12402103.8  29906
0.0 0.0 6741058.6   12582912.0  12402103.8  29906
0.0 0.0 6758686.3   12582912.0  12402103.8  29907
0.0 0.0 6759295.8   12582912.0  12402103.8  29908
0.0 0.0 6764812.4   12582912.0  12402103.6  29908
0.0 0.0 6915819.8   12582912.0  12402103.6  29908
0.0 0.0 6927843.8   12582912.0  12402103.6  29909
0.0 0.0 6936952.4   12582912.0  12402103.6  29910
0.0 0.0 6938582.2   12582912.0  12402027.2  29910
0.0 0.0 6965969.7   12582912.0  12402027.2  29910
0.0 0.0 6965969.7   12582912.0  12402027.2  29911
0.0 0.0 6966291.8   12582912.0  12402027.2  29912
0.0 0.0 7018558.7   12582912.0  12402026.6  29912
0.0 0.0 7021295.9   12582912.0  12402026.6  29912
0.0 0.0 7022254.9   12582912.0  12402026.6  29913
0.0 0.0 7064476.5   12582912.0  12402026.6  29914
0.0 0.0 7067874.0   12582912.0  12402026.4  29914
0.0 0.0 7070544.2   12582912.0  12402026.4  29914
0.0 0.0 7076188.2   12582912.0  12402026.4  29916
0.0 0.0 7076556.2   12582912.0  12402007.2  29916
0.0 0.0 7101610.3   12582912.0  12402007.2  29916
0.0 0.0 7156338.1   12582912.0  12402007.2  29917
0.0 0.0 7158966.6   12582912.0  12402007.2  29918
0.0 0.0 7172960.0   12582912.0  12402007.2  29918
0.0 0.0 7174184.7   12582912.0  12402007.2  29918
0.0 0.0 7278617.7   12582912.0  12402007.2  29919
0.0 0.0 7321347.9   12582912.0  12402007.2  29920
0.0 0.0 7473383.3   12582912.0  12401949.4  29920
0.0 0.0 7478629.0   12582912.0  12401949.4  29920
0.0 0.0 7560124.9   12582912.0  12401949.4  29921
0.0 0.0 7586431.8   12582912.0  12401949.4  29922
0.0 0.0 7587841.2   12582912.0  12401949.1  29922
0.0 0.0 7607755.4   12582912.0  12401949.1  29922
0.0 0.0 7656487.0   12582912.0  12401949.1  29923
0.0 0.0 7662770.1   12582912.0  12401949.1  29924
0.0 0.0 7662770.1   12582912.0  12401949.1  29924
0.0 0.0 7810619.5   12582912.0  12401908.7  29924
0.0 0.0 7915475.2   12582912.0  12401908.7  29924
0.0 0.0 7916589.7   12582912.0  12401908.7  29925
0.0 0.0 7923831.6   12582912.0  12401908.7  29926
0.0 0.0 7927085.1   12582912.0  12401836.2  29926
0.0 0.0 7947903.0   12582912.0  12401836.2  29926
0.0 0.0 7994024.6   12582912.0  12401836.2  29926
0.0 0.0 7994024.6   12582912.0  12401836.2  29927
0.0 0.0 8041582.5   12582912.0  12401836.2  29928
0.0 0.0 8057792.8   12582912.0  12401835.5  29928
0.0 0.0 8151537.0   12582912.0  12401835.5  29928
0.0 0.0 8151551.6   12582912.0  12401835.5  29929
0.0 0.0 8152414.2   12582912.0  12401835.5  29930
0.0 0.0 8159020.1   12582912.0  12401835.5  29930
0.0 0.0 8159020.1   12582912.0  12401834.4  29930
0.0 0.0 8169436.4   12582912.0  12401834.4  29930
0.0 0.0 8170238.0   12582912.0  12401834.4  29931
0.0 0.0 8172264.0   12582912.0  12401834.4  29932
0.0 0.0 8193949.3   12582912.0  12401796.7  29932
0.0 0.0 8194900.5   12582912.0  12401796.7  29932
0.0 0.0 8204694.2   12582912.0  12401796.7  29933
0.0 0.0 8207894.7   12582912.0  12401796.7  29934
0.0 0.0 8207894.7   12582912.0  12401796.7  29934
0.0 0.0 8224413.5   12582912.0  12401796.5  29934
0.0 0.0 8229298.6   12582912.0  12401796.5  29934
0.0 0.0 8233077.3   12582912.0  12401796.5  29935
0.0 0.0 8233100.2   12582912.0  12401796.5  29936
0.0 0.0 8291558.6   12582912.0  12401796.2  29936
0.0 0.0 8294201.9   12582912.0  12401796.2  29936
0.0 0.0 8376223.8   12582912.0  12401796.2  29937
0.0 0.0 8376223.8   12582912.0  12401796.2  29937
0.0 0.0 8430118.2   12582912.0  12401796.2  29938
0.0 0.0 8434741.0   12582912.0  12401710.7  29938
0.0 0.0 8526729.6   12582912.0  12401710.7  29938
0.0 0.0 8555110.4   12582912.0  12401710.7  29939
0.0 0.0 8579409.8   12582912.0  12401710.7  29940
0.0 0.0 8579409.8   12582912.0  12401710.7  29940
0.0 0.0 8695038.1   12582912.0  12401643.6  29940
0.0 0.0 8696711.3   12582912.0  12401643.6  29940
0.0 0.0 8696711.3   12582912.0  12401643.6  29941
0.0 0.0 8737284.3   12582912.0  12401643.6  29942
0.0 0.0 8737284.3   12582912.0  12401643.6  29942
0.0 0.0 8772882.9   12582912.0  12401642.1  29942
0.0 0.0 8775170.0   12582912.0  12401642.1  29942
0.0 0.0 8775170.0   12582912.0  12401642.1  29943
0.0 0.0 8794554.3   12582912.0  12401642.1  29944
0.0 0.0 8794767.2   12582912.0  12401642.1  29944
0.0 0.0 8824500.6   12582912.0  12401581.8  29944
0.0 0.0 8826083.6   12582912.0  12401581.8  29944
0.0 0.0 8826083.6   12582912.0  12401581.8  29945
0.0 0.0 8911554.7   12582912.0  12401581.8  29946
0.0 0.0 8911554.7   12582912.0  12401581.8  29946
0.0 0.0 8958907.7   12582912.0  12401467.2  29946
0.0 0.0 8959676.5   12582912.0  12401467.2  29946
0.0 0.0 8959676.5   12582912.0  12401467.2  29947
0.0 0.0 8964523.1   12582912.0  12401467.2  29948
0.0 0.0 8964523.1   12582912.0  12401467.2  29948
0.0 0.0 8987262.5   12582912.0  12401467.2  29948
0.0 0.0 8992354.3   12582912.0  12401467.2  29948
0.0 0.0 8992354.3   12582912.0  12401467.2  29949
0.0 0.0 8993935.5   12582912.0  12401467.2  29950
0.0 0.0 8993935.5   12582912.0  12401467.2  29950
0.0 0.0 9004951.2   12582912.0  12401466.4  29950
0.0 0.0 9014431.4   12582912.0  12401466.4  29950
0.0 0.0 9014431.4   12582912.0  12401466.4  29951
```

Here are my JVM arguments:

```
-Xloggc:tomcat7/logs/gc.log
-Xmx24g
-Xms24g
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:MaxNewSize=12G
-XX:NewSize=12G
-XX:SurvivorRatio=6
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80
-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=80
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark
-XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=512m
-XX:CMSFullGCsBeforeCompaction=1
-XX:CMSTriggerPermRatio=80
-XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=6000
-XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:ConcGCThreads=6
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=6
-XX:+UseLargePages
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:ThreadStackSize=256
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't deduce anything from this limited data except that Solr is using a lot of memory.  The total memory used (adding up EU and OU) at the end of the jstat output only shows 20.7GB of primary heap in use.  If we assume that the other memory pools have typical sizes, then the total memory in use by Java is probably a little less than 22GB, leaving at least 2GB of heap that's not yet allocated.

Have you run into OutOfMemoryError in your log?  What kind of statistics are there for the indexes that this Solr instance is handling -- number of documents, number of deleted docs, index size, etc?  You would need long term info about garbage collection to make a determination that there's a memory leak.

Memory leaks have been extremely rare in Solr, and I am not aware of any in recent history.

Comment: If there is no memory leak in Solr, then why are FGC-events not clearing up the OU memory? Is there a rough formula I can use to know the heap memory required by Solr for a given number of documents and queries? (Approximate only, need not be accurate).
Note that I have to restart the machines after every few hours because they just take too long to respond to any queries.
In the gc.log too, I see the application threads being stopped too frequently and for about 500 ms per second due to these GC events.

Comment: GC can't free up memory that's still in use.  The memory is still in use.

It's not possible to provide guidelines for heap memory required, even *general* guidelines.  There are simply too many variables.

https://lucidworks.com/blog/sizing-hardware-in-the-abstract-why-we-dont-have-a-definitive-answer/

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems#Java_Heap